# How do I get my spring boot application to accept an absolute uri?

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-boot

When my client application makes a POST request it sets the "Request URI" parameter to an absolute URI such as:

> Request URI: http://myapp.heroku.com/mainpage

When I do this, I get this error response

> 400 Bad Request

if my client application a relative URI like

> Request URI: /mainpage

The request succeeds

Currently my SpringBootApplication has this method

```
  @RequestMapping("/mainpage")
  String index() {
    System.err.println("Hello, logs!");
    return "index";
  }
```

How do I get my application to accept this absolute uri like *http://myapp.heroku.com/mainpage*)??

Comment: If you are using spring boot >2 add context path as server.servlet.context-path=myapp.heroku.com else in controller add @RequestMapping("/myapp.heroku.com") above class name

Comment: that just makes my site respond to:
http://mavt.herokuapp.com/mavt.herokuapp.com/mainpage

That is absolutely not what I want. I am after making the site respond to 
http://mavt.herokuapp.com/mainpage, but I want the request header to be different

Answer (score 1):

In your `application.yaml` in `src\main\resources` set

```
server:
  context-path: /mainpage
```

If you want to replace localhost You can do this in DevOps way and in your (if You are UNIX guy) hosts file `/etc/hosts` add after localhost 127.0.0.1 `myapp.heroku.com` or (if You are Windows guy) `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: is application.yaml different from application.properties?

Comment: Why does this reference port 9010?

Comment: @gregm 9010 is only a simple example if you do not define this you left default port 8080. Application.properties and yaml they are just different data formats. If my answer response of your issue please accept it.

Comment: thanks, however you did not answer my question. Adding context-path only makes my site accept a url like this: myapp.herokuapp.com/myapp.herokuapp.com/mainpage That is absolutely not what I want. I am after making the site respond to myapp.herokuapp.com/mainpage

Comment: Ok, I am glad to know that you reach what you want.

Comment: The question still isn't answered :(

Comment: I have changed response. What is the weirdest is that U client makes a call on an absolute path I recommended fix this.

Comment: I am unable to change the client and also I cannot modify the server like you are suggesting in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to use Jetty as an embedded container and, [as stated in the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations), JSPs are not supported with embedded Jetty:

When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.

With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
Jetty does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.
Undertow does not support JSPs.

[There is a JSP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) so you can see how to set things up.

Comment: How do you know that he use Jetty?  :) and what have JSP to this?

Comment: Since I am running on heroku I don't have much control over the container. Is there any way to change the java code only to support it?

Comment: Also I do not have any jsps. I'm just returning plain text and in the end the url.